# How to change vuex state with mutations

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuex

I'm working on an app, where I'm trying to change Vuex state with mutations, but it doesn't seem to work. At first, `state.status` is an empty string, and I want to update it to `token` variable which is also a string. So in `updateToken` mutation I tried to achieve this. I have also tried something like `Vue.set(state, 'status', token);`, but it also doesn't work (here I had an error: `"Cannot read property 'set' of undefined"`). When I'm trying to send `token` to the second mutation, it's still empty, but console.log() prints the correct token.

Here is my `store.js` code:

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex';
import axios from "axios"

const msgFormData = new FormData();

const store = createStore({
    state: {
        status: "",
    },
    mutations: {
        updateToken(state, token) {
            state.status = token
        },
        sendToken(state, user_name) {
            msgFormData.set('user_name', user_name);
            msgFormData.append('msg_token', state.status);

            axios.post("http://someip/index.php", msgFormData)
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res.status)
            })
            .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
            })
        },
    }
});

export default store;
```

I'm calling these mutations like this:
`this.$store.commit('updateToken', token.value)` in some vue file and
`this.$store.commit('sendToken', this.user.email)` in `App.vue`.

I don't know where I'm doing a mistake, can anybody help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use an [action](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html) instead of a mutation for asynchronous operations like `sendToken`
2. Move `const msgFormData = new FormData();` into the `sendToken` method to create a new instance of `FormData` upon each invocation of the method

Comment: thanks for answer, I'll try to do what you told to improve my code, but I found that token which I wanted to post was too long for my database, and I didn't even thought that could cause my problem.